# Rest API call to see the Work Items IDs in a Query

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Through Azure DevOps's REST API, I'm able to get some info about a Query that I've created:
`https://dev.azure.com/xxx/yyy/_apis/wit/queries/qId1?api-version=5.1`

I'm also (among other things) able to get details about the revisions of a Work Item:
`https://dev.azure.com/xxx/yyy/_apis/wit/workItems/wiId1/updates?api-version=5.1`

But I don't find a call that gives me the work item ids that are targeted by a query.

I would like a call similar to this:
`https://dev.azure.com/xxx/yyy/_apis/workItemIds/queries/qId1?api-version=5.1`

... to deliver something like this:

```json
{ ids: {wiid1, wiid2, wiid3} }
```

Please help me by pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need ["Wiql - Query By Id"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) type of call. Note that the result holds the collection of workItemRelation objects. In case of a flat query the data structure will look like:

```json
    {
      "target": {
        "id": 4,
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workItems/4"
      }
    },
    {
      "target": {
        "id": 5,
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workItems/5"
      }
    },
    {
      "target": {
        "id": 6,
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workItems/6"
      }
    }
```

which is quite similar to what you expect and holds each work item ID.